How can I protect myself from nginx botnet requests?
I received the following requests in nginx docker:
frontend-prod | 206.189.19.19 - - [27/Oct/2024:12:29:42 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 200 600 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
frontend-prod | 206.189.19.19 - - [27/Oct/2024:12:29:43 +0000] "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1" 200 600 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
frontend-prod | 206.189.19.19 - - [27/Oct/2024:12:29:44 +0000] "GET /s/8353e2035313e2331323e2637313/_/;/META-INF/maven/com.atlassian.jira/jira-webapp-dist/pom.properties HTTP/1.1" 200 600 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
frontend-prod | 206.189.19.19 - - [27/Oct/2024:12:29:45 +0000] "GET /config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 600 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
frontend-prod | 206.189.19.19 - - [27/Oct/2024:12:29:46 +0000] "GET /telescope/requests HTTP/1.1" 200 600 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"

There are 2 questions:

I don't have these files, why is the answer 200?
If there were files, how can I protect myself from such attacks, scans, etc.?

I mean my_site.conf:
map $http_user_agent $block_user_agent {
    default 0;
    ~*LWP::Simple 1;
    ~*BBBike 1;
    ~*wget 1;
    ~*msnbot 1;
    ~*scrapbot 1;
    ~*(nmap|nikto|wikto|sf|sqlmap|bsqlbf|w3af|acunetix|havij|appscan) 1;
}

map $http_referer $block_referer {
    default 0;
    ~*(babes|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen) 1;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name MYDOMAIN www.MYDOMAIN;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
        return 444;
    }
    if ($block_user_agent) {
        return 403;
    }
    if ($block_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
    location ~* ^/cgi-bin/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        limit_req zone=req_limit burst=5;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot/;
    }
}

upstream MYDOMAINLAUNCH {
    server mydomainlauncher:6666;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name launcher.MYDOMAIN;
    charset utf-8;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
        return 444;
    }
    if ($block_user_agent) {
        return 403;
    }
    if ($block_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
    location ~* ^/cgi-bin/ {
        deny all;
    }

    root /usr/app/launcher/updates/;

    location / {
        limit_req zone=req_limit burst=5;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        limit_req zone=req_limit burst=5;
        deny all;
    }

    location /api/ {
        limit_req zone=req_limit burst=5;
        proxy_pass http://MYDOMAINLAUNCH;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        error_page 502 = @fallback;
        error_page 504 = @fallback;
    }

    location /webapi/ {
        limit_req zone=req_limit burst=5;
        proxy_pass http://MYDOMAINLAUNCH/webapi/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        error_page 502 = @fallback;
        error_page 504 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        return 302 http://MYDOMAIN;
    }
}

And this is my nginx.conf:
worker_processes 16;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types; # Connecting the mime file.types
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;

    client_body_buffer_size 1K; # Maximum buffer size for storing the client request body
client_header_buffer_size 1k; # Maximum buffer size for storing client request headers
client_max_body_size 1k; # Maximum size of the client request body
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k; # Number and size of buffers for reading a large client request header

    client_body_timeout 10; # Timeout when reading the client
's request body client_header_timeout 10; # Timeout when reading the client's request header
    keepalive_timeout 5 5; # Timeout, after which the keep-alive connection with the client will not be closed from the server side
    send_timeout 10; # Timeout when sending a response to the client

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=slimits:5m; # We describe the zone (slimits) in which the session states will be stored. A 1 MB zone can store about 32,000 states, we set its size to 5 MB
    limit_conn slimits 3; # Setting the maximum number of simultaneous connections per session. In fact, this number sets the maximum number of connections from one IP

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit:10m rate=1r/s;

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block;";
    add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://i0.wp.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" always;
    add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(self), microphone=(), camera=()"; # Replacing Feature-Policy
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;  # Enabling all configurations from conf.d
}

And here is my dockerfile:
###########
# BUILDER #
###########
FROM node:lts-slim AS A builder

# Defining the arguments of the assembly
THE REACT_APP_API_LINK ARGUMENT
THE REACT_APP_API_GETIP ARGUMENT

# Setting environment variables
ENV REACT_APP_API_LINK=$REACT_APP_API_LINK
ENV REACT_APP_API_GETIP=$REACT_APP_API_GETIP

COPY the package file.json with a package lock.json ./
RUN the npm installation && mkdir /react interface && mv ./node_modules ./react interface

WORKDIR /react-
copy interface. .

RUN npm run build

#########
# FINAL #
#########
FROM nginx: latest version

# Copying the build
COPY --from=builder /react-frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Removing the default configuration
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Creating custom Nginx configurations
COPY the nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file
COPY the file my_site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/my_site.conf

# Creating a temporary file system for the root directory
RUN mkdir /nginx && \
mv /usr/share/nginx/html/* /nginx/ &&\
rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html && \
ln -s /nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

# We restrict access to executable files
RUN chmod -R 755 /nginx && \
    find /nginx -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && \
    find /nginx -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

EXPOSE 80

# Run the script and nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon is disabled";"]

Google doesnt work in this questions :(

As you said, this is really 2 questions and should really be asked as two separate questions. I am writing this as an answer to your first question.

I don't have these files, why is the answer 200?

In your configuration for the server you are using try_files:

Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing; the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives. It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”. If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

Spinning up a simple docker container and setting the config as
    location / { 
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html; 
        index  index.html index.htm; 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
    }

If I navigate to any URI and nginx cannot resolve it, it will then try to resolve it as a dir, otherwise it will use the index page.

127.0.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2024:16:28:17 +0000] "GET /sdf HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2024:16:32:54 +0000] "GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2024:16:32:58 +0000] "GET /foo/baz HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2024:16:33:11 +0000] "GET /some/really/long/path/that/doecnt/exist HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0" "-"

These all return 200 success because the last part of you try_files is the index.html which does exist and it what is returned. As you see below doesn't matter that the actual path didn't exist the try_files directive returns me the index page successfully.
Do you really need the try_files declaration?


Yes, thank you, here's the catch, I use a single-page-application on React, so if there is any error, you need it to open anyway index.html and I danced from there (so I use try_files). And about the second question, could you answer? No matter how much I Googled, I didn't find any normal protection, I only found fail2ban, how to set up protection against ddos attacks, and that's it. In addition, unfortunately, gpt was also unable to give much advice on this matter.

Why not use @fallback then in your try files so that it forces a redirect? in regard to DDOS not even fail2ban will help you there. Fail2ban recognises IPs that keep hitting your host and based on config will ban an IP if it comes to often. But a DDOS is generally distributed and will come from many thousands of IP's so fail to ban wont help there. You will likely be overloaded before that worked. If you really need protection at that level use a Saas service like cloudflare or aws sheild to protect you
